# What resources can remote JavaScript access via JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

JSONP is said to "by-pass" the same origin policy.  I take this to mean that using it allows the script to load from a remote server on a different domain and run locally on a website.

I'm not clear however on what exactly can be done by the script while it is running.

Is it just as privileged at JavaScript loaded from the same domain?  Are there any additional restrictions imposed on JSONP that one can count on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a browser, `<script>` tags may reference scripts located in any domain.  Script resources are not subject to the same-origin restrictions that an Ajax request is.

As such, you can dynamically insert a script tag that will refer to a script on any domain and it will load successfully and not be blocked by same origin restrictions.

This is how JSONP works - by making a cross origin request by requesting a remote script to load and run.  It is not a blanket bypass of the same origin restrictions because you cannot just directly make a remote API call using JSONP as the server you are contacting must explicitly support JSONP because it's a completely different type of response.  So, in essence, the server you are contacting must explicitly support and allow this cross origin request via JSONP.

> I'm not clear however on what exactly can be done by the script while
>   it is running.

Once you request a JSONP script, that script is just a piece of Javascript running in your page.  It can literally do anything that any script running in your page can do.

> Is it just as privileged at JavaScript loaded from the same domain?
>   Are there any additional restrictions imposed on JSONP that one can
>   count on?

It's just a script running in your page.  It can do anything that any script running in your page can do.  By convention, it is supposed to call a callback function that was specified in the URL and pass it some data (the result of the request), but it could do any other thing that Javascript in your page can do.

There are no additional restrictions on JSONP scripts.  The browser doesn't know if a script is JSONP script or not.  It's just a script that can do exactly the same things as any other script.

---

JSONP is basically a hack that solved a problem before browsers supported CORS.  I can't think of any reason these days to design a solution based on JSONP any more if you can use CORS.  CORS is more secure as it doesn't let some other site run random Javascript in the context of your page.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP works by employing ordinary `<script>` tags and content fetched as JavaScript via an HTTP GET.  The browser basically thinks it's just fetching another script for use by the page, so the code with which the third-party site responds can do anything it wants to.

"Well-behaved" JSONP sources send back, by convention, a call to the function whose name you give as the "callback" parameter in the URL. That is, the server responds with a JavaScript statement:

```
yourCallback({ name: value, ... });
```

There's really no way for your code on the page to tell whether that's really all that happened, however.